# Using savon gem for SOAP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

When I add this to my Gemfile :

```
gem 'savon', '~> 2.0'
```

And run `bundle install`. And try to start a `rails console` I get this error :

```
app/models/user.rb:6:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
    from app/models/user.rb:6:in `<class:User>'
    from app/models/user.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Removing gem removes the issue, what's the problem I really don't know how to take it from here. Any suggestions?

**Update (ruby version output):**

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin13.2.0]
```

**Update II** (relevant model bit):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include InstanceMethodsOnActivation
  include GoingPostal
  include UUID
  include Wizard
  include PublicActivity::Common
```

line 3 is the class definition and the line 6 is the UUID. Here is the uuid :

```
module UUID
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def uuid
    HASHIDS.encrypt(id)
  end

  def to_param
    uuid
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def find_by_uuid(uuid)
      self.find_by_id(HASHIDS.decrypt(uuid)) unless uuid.nil?
    end

    def find_by_uuid!(uuid)
      self.find_by_id!(HASHIDS.decrypt(uuid)) unless uuid.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the code of user model?

Comment: @liuzxc yes I'll update in a sec

Comment: You try to include a class, which is not possible in ruby.

Comment: @liuzxc not sure what exactly you mean, where did you see that I'm including class. Sorry I'm tired can't see what you mean? the UUID is a module..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the dependencies of the savon gem is the uuid gem, which provides a `UUID` class.

In development mode where application code is only loaded on demand this means that your uuid file is never loaded and `UUID` is the class from the gem.

In production, depending on where the file is and your eager load settings rails would probably try and load your file at app startup and you'd get an error because you're creating a class with the same name as a module

The simplest thing would be to rename your module - either pick a different name entirely or namespace it.